# MySQL limit 1 returns the last record of result set of order by?

Tags: mysql, limit

1.I create a table

```
create table sort (
 a int,
 b int,
primary key (a));
```

2.Then i inserted three records

```
insert into sort values(1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 10);
```

3.When i select use this sql

```
select * from sort order by b;
```

It gives the result like this

```
+---+------+
| a | b    |
+---+------+
| 1 |   10 |
| 2 |   10 |
| 3 |   10 |
+---+------+
```

4. When I select the table use this query

   select * from sort order by b limit 1;

And the result set is this

```
+---+------+
| a | b    |
+---+------+
| 3 |   10 |
+---+------+
```

And this not what I excepted (I thought the return the first record would be reasonable).

My mysql version is Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.23, for osx10.8 (x86_64)

Can any explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: why should it return the first one ? you are ordering by the column 'B' , column 'A' is irrelevant , MySQL will store the data in files not the same way as you see in GUI , it sorts the table and grabs the column with the lowest 'B' value , is there any row with the lower 'B' ? no, this means query is correct , if you want the first row to be returned , then add order by b,a

Comment: Interesting. I tried it (using innodb and myisam, in case that made a difference), and got the first row (a=1) as the result with limit 1 (as you expected).

Comment: @ogres add that as an answer

Comment: It's still not an explanation. Sure, there's nothing wrong with mysql returning any of the 3 rows, but I for one would prefer an actual explanation of the behaviour. I've tried to replicate it, and I can't.

Comment: you expect this `order by b asc or desc `

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you type `select * from sort order by b;` this will load with hidden field of `ACS`. It means **query load all date with Ascending  order**.

```
+---+------+
| a |   b  |
+---+------+
| 1 |  10  |
| 2 |  10  |
| 3 |  10  |
+---+------+
```

But if you use `select * from sort order by b limit 1;` it again load data with `ACS` and then you have condition with `LIMIT 1`. So in `b` column all are `10` so it will load last added value of that.

> Bz `MySQL` will decide last added row is the newest one

Answer (score 0):

This SQL Server has returned the reasonable record already.
Because, you order by the column that has the same quantity (evaluate by service).

Step that SQL Server do is ::

    Check is it has indexing -> Read table from disk/index -> Sort data -> Get n number of sorted data. 


(n from your query)

So, this SQL Server will return the first one that it has found within the main table from disk (Storage) because u have not index it.

Unless you order by a,b. 

You will get 1,10 as your results.

Or create an index that make the order of your data different. (You also can get 2,10 as result)

Otherwise , you will get the first inserted data to disk as your results.

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually explain the behaviour, because I can't replicate it. But I can demonstrate that what the OP expected is how my mysql ( Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (i686)) works [NB, I'm inserting the records in a different order, to prove a point):

First, with no primary key:

```
mysql> create table sort (
    ->  a int,
    ->  b int);
mysql> insert into sort values (3,10),(2,10), (1,10);
mysql> select * from sort order by b limit 1;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    3 |   10 |
+------+------+
```

The first inserted record is displayed

And with a primary key:

```
mysql> create table sort (
    ->  a int,
    ->  b int,
    -> primary key (a));
mysql> insert into sort values (3,10),(2,10), (1,10);
mysql> select * from sort order by b limit 1;
+---+------+
| a | b    |
+---+------+
| 1 |   10 |
+---+------+
```

This is a myisam table (the default on my server), so the table has a clustered index, which causes the table to be read in the order of column a. Hence, a=1 is the first record (I believe).

Finally, using innodb:

```
mysql> create table sort (  a int,  b int, primary key (a) ) engine=myisam;
mysql> insert into sort values (3,10),(2,10), (1,10);
mysql> select * from sort order by b limit 1;
+---+------+
| a | b    |
+---+------+
| 3 |   10 |
+---+------+
```

No clustered index, so the first record entered is returned.

None of this explains what the OP claims, but I can't make it occur.

Comment: primary key of innodb table is not a clustered index?

Comment: The primary key of a myisam table is not a clustered index. That's why the myisam and the innodb examples differ (I think).